# Nested PreferenceScreen, when called, replacing Whole Screen

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-tabactivity

I wrapped my PreferenceActivity within a TabActivity. Thing looks good. but when I introduced "2nd level PreferenceScreen" to my PreferenceActivity and when someone clicked on it, it replaces the whole screen. is there anywhere I can retain my tab above when the 2nd screen opens up? and, how can I make open/exit animation when people clicking into the 2nd level preference screen? I would like to have the old screen sliding to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there anywhere I can retain my tab above when the 2nd screen opens up?

Not that I am aware of. Bear in mind that nested `PreferenceScreens` are deprecated, and you will not want to use them on Android 3.0+.

> and, how can I make open/exit animation when people clicking into the 2nd level preference screen?

AFAIK, you cannot control this.

Comment: alright. thanks for the feedback! I have revamped my design to use listView with custom adapter instead.